# Mount root filesystem from initramfs

Tags: boot, opensuse, startup, initramfs, root-filesystem

It's a common scenario. For whatever reason, the initramfs (OpenSUSE, in case it matters) has failed to find the root filesystem, so it drops you into a rescue shell. I know perfectly well what device needs to be mounted though. My question:

**What is the correct procedure to mount the root filesystem and continue the boot sequence?**

Presumably that's the whole *point* of the rescue console. And yet, nobody seems to have documented how you actually do this.

Obviously I can mount the root filesystem somewhere. But how do I make that the *root* of the filesystem tree? And now do I continue the normal boot process after that? (I thought just exiting the shell would do it... but it doesn't.) What exactly do you need to get mounted before you continue, and how do you continue?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think once you're in a rescue shell you can't continue the current boot, you fix things so the next boot will succeed

Comment: @EricRenouf manually booting the full system may very well be the easiest way to fix such an issue. I had problems in the past where the initramfs failed to open my cryptsetup-luks encrypted root partition, and the easiest fix was to manually boot it and then run `update-initramfs -u`. I absolutely couldn't get it working when I just `chroot`ed into the root filesystem from a rescue system; the resulting initramfs was always broken.

Comment: Is it actually an initrd, or an initramfs? (Just because the file is called `initrd` doesn't mean that it's one: most distributions have switched to `initramfs` but keep calling the file `initrd`.) **What distribution are you using** (as what the initrd/initramfs does depends on what the distribution put there)?

Comment: @Gilles I'm pretty sure it's actually initramfs. Not sure if it actually makes a difference though; either way, I've got a mini filesystem and I need to mount the real filesystem. (OpenSUSE, in case it matters.)

Answer (score 15):

```
exec switch_root /mnt/root /sbin/init
```

https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#Init

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the kind of problem, if the problem was borking the initramfs image itself then you'll need to actually regenerate it (run update-initramfs) to fix things. Remember the initramfs file system is a RAM filesystem, so to fix anything you need to fix the compressed initramfs image and/or fix the root filesystem.

I've used the following procedure on an LUKS encrptyed Ubuntu system in order to resume a boot broken by a bad crypttab.

First, I decrypted the partition

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p3 nvme0n1p3_crypt
```

Note the `device_crypt` isn't random. It needs to match the name that's normally used when your system mounts (partition + _crypt seems to be standard).

Next, you need to activate the Volume Groups on that now-decrpyted partition.

```
vgchange -ay
```

Now, you can try mounting the file systems, /, /boot, proc, swap, etc, and getting things running that way.

Though in my case all I had to do was type exit and initramfs saw the logical volumes sitting there and happily resumed the boot. At that point it was easy to fix the damange and run `update-initramfs -u`

Comment: Where do you mount /, /boot, etc *to*?  I think that was the question - and it's certainly mine, stuck as I am in a very similar situation.

Comment: @Diagon, you can mount the /, /boot etc. in any directory in the initramfs. Then, you can go inside that directory to find all your files and make necessary fixes.

Comment: @SadmanSakib / thanks, but once mounted, is there a way to then continue the boot sequence?

Comment: @Diagon, the way to continue boot sequence depends on the issue. In my case, my default grub menu had to be corrected. So, I opened `grub.cfg` with vim, made changes and rebooted the computer.

Comment: @Diagon On a Ubuntu 22.04, I had to mount on `/root`. But when the problem is not too deep, you just need to setup cryptsetup/lvm/etc. and exit from the initramfs prompt (with Ctrl+D or `exit`) so that the init scripts can find the devices of /etc/fstab and pick up from there.
As a memento, here are a few of the commands I used : `cryptsetup open /dev/sda5 mycrypt ; lvm lvs ; mount -t auto /dev/ubuntu-vg/root /root ; mount -t auto /dev/sda1 /root/boot ; mount -t proc none /root/proc ; mount -t sysfs none /root/sysfs`

Comment: @Chl / Useful, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Simply run `fsck` command without options from `initramfs` then reboot

eg: the root partition is `sda3`

```
fsck /dev/sda3
```

Comment: The reboot just dropped me to grub shell instead of initramfs shell. Now I'll do [everything](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux) over again to get to initramfs shell

Comment: This worked for me. `reboot` didn't do anything, but simply running `exit` after completing the checks continued the booting process, now with a good file system.

Comment: I had a similar [problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/648824/stuck-at-busy-box-attempt-to-boot-old-linux-at-another-partition) running fsck give clean. But I still won't able to boot normally.

Answer (score 2):

If the `root=` parameter is correct and the issue is just that the necessary device isn't available (for example because the initramfs failed to assemble an `md` RAID), then it's enough to make the device available manually, for example:

```
mdadm --assemble ...
```

Then check that the device is there and if everything looks good, hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> or type `exit` to quit the initramfs shell. The initramfs will then mount the root filesystem and continue to boot as usual. After the system has booted, you should then repair the underlying issue, for example by running `update-initramfs -u`.

I haven't yet found a way to tell the initramfs to boot a different device than what `/proc/cmdline` says. Maybe someone else has an idea?

Comment: i'd gotten stuck due to a recuse cd hard coding a specific md number, md127, when the booting kernel assigned the number md0, i got out of this was a symlink and an update-grub +  update-initramfs afterward restoring the UUID behavior. `# ln /dev/md0 /dev/md127; exit`

Answer (score 1):

normal procedure is

1. mount /dev/sdX /mnt
2. fix problem on /mnt
3. reboot

You might want to

1. mount /dev/sdX /mnt
2. fix /mnt
3. umount /mnt
4. mount /dev/sdX /
5. finish boot manualy

This is not recommended, you'll have to do it on every boot. 
In a production environment, you can't be sure manual boot follow same steps as automatic one.

However in a emergency with critical data, step 5 usualy boil down to:

- 5.1 set up network
- 5.2 copy important file to safe place

Comment: I believe the "actual" question of the original poster was "How exactly do you do '5. finish boot manualy'?"

Answer (score 1):

Using the existing answers, I had trouble finding the mount point I need to use for the root. In my case, on ArchLinux, it was `/new_root`. The full steps for resuming boot (assuming a bad `crypttab`) were:

```shell
cryptsetup open /dev/nvme1n1p2 root
mount /dev/mapper/SomeVolGroup/root /new_root
```

Then, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the root filesystem is not found because the corresponding device is not seen by linux kernel (even though it can be seen from the "BIOS").

This happened on two of my computers, which are Dell laptops. The reason was that the "BIOS" on these Dell computers has an option whether it will present the hard drives as RAID or AHCI. If RAID is selected, linux is not able to see the device, and hence not able to find my usual root filesystem.

Of course, in such a situation (after the setting in this modern "BIOS" has been reset to its default "RAID" value), there is nothing that you can do from the initramfs even manually (like finding the path to the device and mounting it, and continuing the boot procedure with `init`, which is the common advice). Change the setting in the "BIOS".